# Regex: Match words that only contain certain letters

Tags: regex

I am using a Regex dictionary located [here](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/), and want to find words that contain ONLY the following letters: `B, C, D, E, H, I, K, O.`  So, for example: `cod, hoe, and hob.`

I thought the simple way of doing this would be with the following regex query: `[bcdehiko]+`, but this yields many words that contain at least one instance of the bracketed letters, and any other letter.

Comment: `\b[bcdehiko]+\b` with word boundary should work.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713232/3832970 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713544/3832970

Comment: In python you don't even need regex: `print(all(x in l for x in s))` where `s` is your word and `l` is your list of characters.

Comment: Edited link, sorry.

Comment: @anubhava you should post it as an alternative answer to mine below - for anyone that wants to use regex or isn't looking for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that website, the easiest solution is to combine your started regex with line start and line end matches. This will ensure that the word contains nothing but the characters you want. Here is the regex you want to use to get your results:

```
^[bcdehiko]+$
```

If you're okay with `-` in words, you can use this as well:

```
^[bcdehiko]+(-[bcdehiko]+)*$
```

Credit to @ctwheels for the improvement on the second regex.

Comment: `^[bcdehiko]([-bcdehiko]*[bcdehiko])?$` should be changed to `^[bcdehiko]+(-[bcdehiko]+)*$`

Comment: @ctwheels That is a nicer regex, I agree

Comment: P.S. if anyone is wondering how to extract such words from a sentence; best option is to split the sentence on whitespace `\s+` and then test each word against the regex Swiss provided above. Using boundaries is also possible, but it over-complicates the pattern when other characters like `-` are involved: e.g. `(?:(?<=\s)|^)[bcdehiko]+(-[bcdehiko]+)*(?=\s|$)` - only works in some regex engines

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified a language (and I think that others looking for such answers might find this useful), here is an answer to your question in [python](/questions/tagged/python) without the use of regex.

```
l = 'bcdehiko'
d = ['cod', 'codz']

for w in d:
    print(all(x in l for x in w))
```

This method loops over the *dictionary** `d` and ensures all characters in that word exists in the string `l`. See it working [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0fBVkE9KTklNSMzO1@dKwXIjVZPzk9R11EAUVXqsVxcaflFCuUKmXkKKVZcCkBQUJSZV6KRmJOjUQESzVEAKQAzyzU1//8HAA).

<sub>* dictionary in the OP's original question refers to a dictionary in the wordbook sense, not in the computing sense.
In the script, the variable `d` is a list.</sub>

---

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that a word contains at least one character from a list of characters, you can replace `any` with `all` in the above script (you can test by adding the word `ran` to the list `d` - which doesn't contain a single letter in the list `d`). See it working [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0fBVkE9KTklNSMzO1@dKwXIjVZPzk9R11EAUVUguigxTz2Wiystv0ihXCEzTyHFiksBCAqKMvNKNBLzKjUqQKI5CiAFYGa5pub//wA).

Comment: OP said he's trying to use this tool here: https://www.visca.com/regexdict/

Comment: @CAustin thank you for the clarification - link wasn't working initially. I'll leave this here for anyone that isn't using that specific tool (since it's not specifically tagged in the question)

Answer (score 0):

You are using this regex:

```
[bcdehiko]+
```

Which means match one or more instances of given characters in square brackets.

However this regex will also allow matching other characters in a word since there is no word boundary in use.

You may want to wrap your regex with `\b` on either side to ensure there are no other characters allowed:

```
\b[bcdehiko]+\b
```

Comment: Word bounds don't work, since they will match on `-`. That means a word like `co-dependent` would match.

Comment: @Swiss if we're going to be specific with `-`, we should add that other characters should also be included since they're also valid characters in English words: `é` in `fiancé`, `à` in `déjà vu`, `'` in `D'oh`, etc. - all valid English words. The OP never specified what the list of words contains or what the dictionary's base is.

Comment: @ctwheels That's an interesting question -- it would seem like all those examples should match.